# Windows 10 startup 'icon' freeze

Tags: windows-10, freeze, desktop

During the startup of the system after login at some point that freeze happens. The icons on the desktop are stuck in that un-loaded placeholder image and the programs I try to run don't start neither. After a minute or so suddenly everything jumps back to normal. Icons load instentanously, programs start etc. It happens after my PC is shutdown for more than few hours.

Comment: Are you able to move the mouse etc. or is it entirely frozen?

Comment: The mouse is perfectly well. Other odd behavior is the firefox starts and works correctly but other progrems don't.

Comment: Are those programs installed on different drives? So maybe your drive isn't able to load data?

Comment: Well some of them are but it didn't happen before. I'm using 240 GB SSD as main and 1TB HDD as second, by the way. It should't be the issue of disc read speed AFAIK as system is on SSD. Besides, my last statistics tell that the HDD is doing well and returns minimum errors.

Comment: While the disk might be fine the channel might be saturated. Maybe there is an AV scan running or similar?